# Piwik issues while tracking the website

Tags: javascript, android, matomo

I am using piwik for maintaining analytics of my website. have copy pasted the java script code before  tag on all pages.But nothing is happening visitors in real time not incremented plus on all tabs there is no data.

```
<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];
  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function() {
    var u="//piwik-techforumatos.rhcloud.com/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
  })();
</script>
<noscript><p><img src="//piwik-techforumatos.rhcloud.com/piwik.php?idsite=1" style="border:0;" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

Any suggestion on this or is i am doing  any wrong thing.

Have gone through below url also but no luck.

http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript

---

UPDATE:-

Have searched a lot and final i got the solution kindly got through below url:

1. https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/8341
2. https://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_20304/

Comment: Have you added this code in the html header?

Answer (score 0):

Check your requests (press F12). Maybe you need to change the url (add https prefix):

//piwik-techforumatos.rhcloud.com/

to:

https://piwik-techforumatos.rhcloud.com/

Do this to other urls in piwik code.